# convert array of hashes to array of values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I am an array of hashes and I want to convert it to array of values something like this

array of hashes `[{text: "James"},{text: "developer"}]`
convert this to
array of values `["James", "Developer"]`

Please help me achieve this in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.values`, you can get the values of each object.

```js
const input = [{text: "James"},{text: "developer"}];

const output = input.flatMap((item) => Object.values(item));
console.log(output);
```